# Is there a general rule to footnoting acronyms/initialisms in tables?

Tags: paper-submission

Rarely do journal submission guidelines address *each* aspect of presentation. With tables, a common authorship point is which values require a footnote. Sometimes with very obvious things, the team insists on adding a footnote (such as CI = Confidence Interval), and on other times they argue things are so obvious and don't need a footnote (such as BMI = Body Mass Index).

Is it acceptable to forego footnotes if you feel a particular initialism is obvious to the readership?

Comment: Writing for the convenience of your target audience and a bit beyond can be a pretty good guide.

Comment: Look at tables in various articles in the journal you are targeting. Frankly, most published tables have plenty of room to spell out any acronyms.

Comment: The general rule is that no acronym is obvious enough that it does not need to be explained, either in a footnote or somewhere else in the text at the first occurrence.

Comment: Depends upon the journal. Some say define in each table and figure. I would read your target journal's recent issues to see what people do. Also, the Council for Science Editors' 8th Edition Style Guide might be the most authoritative style guide across fields, but others exist such as APA and MLA.

Answer (score 4):

Jon Custer says:

> Look at tables in various articles in the journal you are targeting. Frankly, most published tables have plenty of room to spell out any acronyms.

Snijderfrey says:

> The general rule is that no acronym is obvious enough that it does not need to be explained, either in a footnote or somewhere else in the text at the first occurrence.

I think those comments pretty much sum it up. I think it's worth considering that even obvious acronyms are not obvious to everyone, and it's easy to drift into an area where acronyms conflict and someone's immediate thought is a different acronym than the one you intend, and Visitors From The Future may even have a different perspective than anyone you can find today. Are those confidence intervals or credible intervals?

I would make an exception for anacronyms like "laser" and "scuba". In many cases you won't have to make a decision directly because the journal will have a style guide that specifies whether any acronyms can be skipped.

Comment: Thanks for writing up the answer. My first take on CI was continuous integration...

Comment: @Snijderfrey - well, I come up with counterintelligence, which is even more likely to be wrong...

Comment: Small point, but scuba is no longer an acronym according to some dictionaries. I learned this a NAUI scuba instructor. For example,  https://web.archive.org/web/20160925160356/https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scuba

Comment: @JonCuster Configuration interaction comes to mind too.

Comment: @RichardErickson That's what an anacronym is.